# Center lables and input fields vertically

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I have a screen with several inputs and labels ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vPqw/1/)).
How can I center the labels vertically relatively to the controls?

Obviously, they only should be centered when the label is shown on the same line as the control.

By now, I have this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="dispInlineLabel" >
    <label for="ti_gebdat">Geburtsdatum</label>
</div>
<div class="dispInline">       
    <input name="ti_gebdat" id="ti_gebdat" style="text-align: right" type="date"  data-theme="d">
</div>
<div class="clearFloats"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.dispInline, .dispInlineLabel{
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom-width:0;
}
.dispInline{
    float:right;
    width:270px;
    text-align:right;
}
.clearFloats{
    clear:both;
}

@media all and (max-width: 410px){
  .dispInline{
      text-align:left;
      width:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7vPqw/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not wrapped your form inputs inside `label`, i would suggest you to separate their styling....this would solve your problem and **provide greater independence for label designing** , also, solves your purpose :) 

**CSS :**

```
   .dispInline
{
    float:right;
    width:270px;
    text-align:right;
}
.dispInlineLabel{
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom-width:0;
    float:left;
    line-height:4.0em;

}


.clearFloats{
    clear:both;
}

@media all and (max-width: 410px){
  .dispInline{
      text-align:left;
      width:100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML markup is really messy, but try adding this to your CSS:

```
.dispInlineLabel {
    line-height: 40px;
    margin: 0.5em 0;
}

label.ui-input-text {
    line-height: inherit;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7vPqw/8/